# What is the basic memory-making algorithm?

Tags: memory, neural-network, language, linguistics, language-processing

What are the fundamental criteria that determine the hierarchy of saved information in the brain?

I've discovered that our languages reflect some of those factors. One of them can be sex identification - I've noticed this when I was reading *The story of your life*, I couldn't really imagine the character of the main hero without the knowledge of her sex.

Another criterium could be time. In many languages, an event cannot be expressed without the knowledge of the time it had taken place.

Do we know what is the fundamental hierarchy of creating memories (I accept a very broad answer :)?

Comment: Hi @Probably:  I am voting to close, it is simply too broad and has some speculative and hard to follow sources, hierarchy of memories is also a contested complex concept, memory is not an unitary concept and on an on, couple of book recommendations: The oxford Handbook of memory (Tulving) ,Memory: From Mind to Molecules (Kandel) and Learning and Memory (Gluck)

Comment: @Keno Thank you, then, I'll look at those and try to narrow it